# How to insert <ProgrammArguments> in a launchd-.plist on os x

Tags: string, macos, shell, plist, rsync

is it possible to implement the following .sh-script completly into a launchd-.plist?

```
#!/bin/sh
rsync -avuz --delete -e '/usr/bin/ssh -i /Users/FOO/.ssh/id_rsa' /Users/Shared/Backup/ root@333.444.555.666:/volume1/NetBackup/BAR/
```

this one doesn´t work:

```
…
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
     <string>/usr/bin/rsync</string>
     <string>-avuz</string>
     <string>--delete</string>
     <string>-e '/usr/bin/ssh -i /Users/FOO/.ssh/id_rsa'</string>
     <string>/Users/Shared/Backup/</string>
     <string>root@333.444.555.666:/volume1/NetBackup/BAR/</string>
</array>
…
```

With the separate shell script it´s working fine – I just don´t want to call a script if not necessary.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-e` and the string after it are separate arguments:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>rsync</string>
  <string>-avuz</string>
  <string>--delete</string>
  <string>-e</string>
  <string>ssh -i /Users/FOO/.ssh/id_rsa</string>
  <string>/Users/Shared/Backup/</string>
  <string>root@333.444.555.666:/volume1/NetBackup/BAR/</string>
</array>
```

If you add `<key>EnableGlobbing</key><true/>`, you can replace `/Users/FOO/` with `~/`.

You can also embed a script by using `bash -c`:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>bash</string>
  <string>-c</string>
  <string>while sleep 5; do say a; done</string>
</array>
```

Comment: thank you for the '-e' hint … now it works like a charm - and no extra script needed.